# Attribute with this code is not super in row - magento 2

Tags: configurable-product, magento-2.1.1

Can't import configurable products in magento 2.1 getting validation error like **Attribute with this code is not super in row** in configurable variation column

Comment: your attributes value having scope is not global, first check if attributes used in config product csv have scope global or not?

Comment: is_global filed in attribute.csv is already set as global

Comment: no i am talking about attribute code, which are used in config product, use scope as global in attrbute details page. Like if you have used size as config super attribute, you have to go size attribute admin page , set scope as global inside Advanced Attribute Properties section in admin

Comment: under Advanced Attribute Properties scope is shown as global, but still getting the same error

Comment: have you checked all those attributes which are used as config super product

Comment: I am also having the same issue, is this issue fixed for you?

Answer (score 15):

Two Points you need to check for this:

1. Scope of attribute is Global.
2. It should be assigned to Attribute Set.

Hope this solved the error. 
(For my case i missed Point 2, Now it is imported successfully !!!)

Comment: "It should be assigned to Attribute Set." That's my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if mispelled attribute name.

In my case, when I copy data from Excel to OpenOffice it cuts off some fields. For instance, I import configurable products and there is `configurable_variations` field which has a lot of characters. It is cut when copying therefore error shows up when importing.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur if you neglect to set the **Apply To** option to **Simple Product** and **Configurable Product** in the Attribute Properties.  Also check the Use To **Create Configurable Product** property as well.

Comment: Is this in reference to M1 or M2, I'm having trouble finding this option is M2.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to create a configurable parent using attributes that are not Dropdown. Ensure that the attribute you are using is Dropdown and the available attribute values exist.

Comment: Please describe more. For what you want to ask

Comment: @Msquare Thank you but I do not have a question, I was offering admin advice on the above thread question as I have experienced this problem from my team before. It is not really an error in Magento, it was an error in product knowledge where people were trying to build configuration using non-super attributes (e.g. attribute that is a type different from Dropdown)